# Where to Add Code to Make Cuberto Liquid Swipe Work in Android Studio 2023?

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I want to use the cuberto liquid swipe on Android Studio, but on the new version there are no allprojects dependency. Where can I add the code for it to work on android studio 2023?

```
def githubProperties = new Properties()
    githubProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("github.properties")))
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"

            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android")
            credentials {
                /** Create github.properties in root project folder file with     
                ** gpr.usr=GITHUB_USER_ID & gpr.key=PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN 
                ** Or set env variable GPR_USER & GPR_API_KEY if not adding a properties file**/
                username = githubProperties['gpr.usr'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER")
                password = githubProperties['gpr.key'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY")
            }
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/Cuberto/liquid-swipe-android

I tried adding the code to `setting.grandle` but it didn't work.